# How to look the frame number of rtabmap in ROS instead of using rtabmapviz

Tags: ros, slam-algorithm

I use rtabmap as my RGB-D SLAM application and I just want to check the performance of rtabmap running on different machines. I don't want to use rtabmapviz because it contains to much information and I just need frame number and the final map. So is there any way to check the frame number instead of using rtabmapviz?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and My ROS version is ROS indigo.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the topic informations about frame topic. You can use rqt_gui tools and choose topic console, it will show you more information about it.